# Docker Swarm outgoing communication via Container Host or Swarm-Manager?

Tags: docker, email, networking, gateway, swarm

I have several Docker-Swarm nodes with 1 to n service-Containers.

How is external communication from those service-containers realized in Docker?

I do have a mail-server which is on a different network than the swarm divided by a firewall.
When I do wish to send mails via smtp using my mail-server which IP would I have to whitelist in the Firewall?
The manager node or all the worker nodes?
On the other hand is there any way to configure the swarm to initiate communications from the containers using the manager as gateway?

I hope this was not too confusing and/or complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Routing entire outbound traffic through the selected node kinda defeat the purpose behind swarm cluster I think. There is possibility to use external load balancer instead of swarm routing mesh, but it will affect only inbound, not outgoing connections.

In case of `SMTP` traffic you could use simple mail relay service like [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/). Install it on selected node of your cluster, send mail from any container to it, and then `Davmail` will route mail to your actual server. Then you will need whitelist only this node on your firewall.